# How does the JDBCJobStore work .?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

So I started to tinker around with `JDBCJobStore` in `Quartz`. Firstly, I could not find a single good resource on how to configure it from scratch. After looking for it for a while and singling out a good resource for beginners, I downloaded the sample application at [Job scheduling with Quartz](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-quartz/). I have a few doubts regarding it.

- **How does `JDBCJobStore` capture jobs**.? I mean in order for the job to get stored in the database does the job have to run manually once.? Or will JDBCJobStore automatically detect the jobs and their details..?
- **How does `JDBCJobStore` schedule the jobs**.? Does it hit the database at a fixed interval like a **heartbeat** to check if there are any scheduled jobs.? Or does it keep the `triggers` in the memory while the application is running.?
- In order to run the jobs **will I have to manually specify the details of the job like like name and group and fetch the trigger** accordingly.? Is there any alternative to this.?
- On each application restart **how can I tell the scheduler to start automatically**..? Can it be specified somehow.?

Comment: I have written a blog post on Quartz that uses a REST API to schedule jobs and uses liquibase to manage database migrations.    http://juliuskrah.com/tutorial/2017/10/06/persisting-dynamic-jobs-with-quartz-and-spring/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using servlet/app server you can start it during startup:

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/ServletInitScheduler

If you are running standalone you have to initialize it manually i think.

You can read more about JobStores here:

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09

And about jobs and triggers:

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-02

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-03

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-04

I guess that quartz checks jobs based on time interval to proper work in clusters and distributed systems.

Comment: Does this mean that if i'm using something like `SpringMVC` I won't have to run the job's manually once for them to get stored to the DB.. ?

Comment: Correct. If you add `JobStore` and `Scheduler` definition to Spring context it will start during server startup and pickup jobs from db if there are stored any. You should never run job manually.

Comment: I don't understand. I get the `Scheduler` on startup part. What I don't understand is how will the jobs get stored.? How will I tell quartz that there are 2 jobs in my application without any manual work like running the job once or entering the values in the DB.. ?

Comment: You have to `schedule` job using `QuartzScheduler`. After job is scheduled Quartz will run this job in scheduled time. take a look on http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/1.8.5/org/quartz/core/QuartzScheduler.html `schedule` method

Comment: Does this mean I have to write `scheduler.start()` somewhere in my code.? If yes, doesn't it kind of ruin the whole point of bootstrapping quartz.? Where should I write it.?

Comment: use `SchedulerFactoryBean` as mentioned in: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/